# Non-integral constraints in calculus of variations

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

This is from Daniel Liberzon's book on Optimal Control, see section 2.5.2 in http://liberzon.csl.illinois.edu/teaching/cvoc.pdf.

Consider a basic calculus of variations problem:
$$
J(y) = \int_a^b L(x,y,y')dx
$$

where $y = y(x)$ and $L : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the Lagrangian. Now consider an equality constraint
$$
M(x, y, y') = 0 \;\;\; \forall x \in [a,b]
$$

Liberzon states that the Euler-Lagrange equation must hold for the augmented Lagrangian then:
$$
L + \lambda^*(x)M
$$

and this is equivalent to considering the minimization of 
$$
\int_a^b Ldx + \int_a^b \lambda^*(x)Mdx
$$

Note that Liberzon misses out the asterisk for $\lambda^*(x)$ in the second integral, but I assume that is a typo. Albeit he is persistent with missing it in the next few sentences.

He then states that $\lambda$ no longer needs to be constant, since $M$ is identically 0.

My question is basically what's going on here? If $M=0$ $\forall x \in [a,b]$, then why do we even have the second integral? I understand the derivation of the augmented Euler-Lagrange equation in section 2.5.1 with the integral constraint and why the Lagrange multiplier is there, but in this case whatever we pick as $\lambda$, the second integral vanishes.

In fact, he goes on to compare this sum of integrals to equation (2.51) which leads to the same situation. Can anyone explain?

P.S. I know my question is a bit of a mess, so if anything is clear, do ask for clarification!

Comment: I think you are a bit confused here with the Lagrange multiplier method. Don't you think it is strange already in the two-dimensional case that to minimize $f(x)$ subject to $g(x)=0$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$, we work with the Lagrangian $L(x,\lambda)=f(x)+\lambda g(x)$? It is the same question there: what's the point with $\lambda g(x)$ term if $g(x)=0$, i.e. vanishes anyway? P.S. The difference between $\lambda^*$ and $\lambda$ is that the former is the *optimal* Lagrange multiplier.

Comment: Good point. We want to minimize $f(x)$ while maintaining the constraint $g(x) = 0$. Because of the additional information that is the constraint, we can restrict the problem and thus have to solve for $f(x)$ and $\lambda$. Same in my question. We are interested in minimizing the contributions of $L$ and $M$ where whenever the constraint is met, $M = 0$. Anyway, a bit more reading until I'm fully convinced but thanks for showing me where my understanding was lacking!

Comment: For one constraint you need one multiplier $f(x)+\lambda g(x)$, for two constraints you need two of those $f(x)+\lambda_1g_1(x)+\lambda_2g_2(x)$, for $N$ many you get $f(x)+\sum_{k=1}^N\lambda_kg_k(x)$. Now you have *continuum many*, one for each $x$. How should the Lagrangian look like? NB $x$ in your case is exactly the summation index, the unknown is $y$.

Comment: The Lagrangian will look like $L + \lambda(x)M$. The Lagrange multiplier is now a function defined as $\lambda : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So instead of solving for $x$ and $\lambda$, I'm solving for $y(x)$ and $\lambda(x)$.

Comment: The unknowns are: $y(x)$ and $\lambda(x)$, the equations are: E-L and $M=0$. Plus some boundary conditions. Normally they are "just enough" to find the unknowns.